# python dataframe select rows based on cell which is a list from a list

Tags: python, dataframe, arraylist, rows

I want to select rows of a dataframe based on a column of lists.  I want to select a row based on the intersection of a seperate stand-alone list.  I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to do this since I've spent several hours researching and my solution is still not complete.

```py
import pandas as pd  

# initialize list of lists  
data = [['DS', 'Linked_list', 10, ['a', 'b', 'c']], 
        ['DS', 'Stack', 9, ['d', 'e', 'c']], 
        ['DS', 'Queue', 7, ['f', 'g', 'i']], 
        ['Algo', 'Greedy', 8, ['r', 's', 'c']], 
        ['Algo', 'DP', 6, ['t', 'r', 'g']], 
        ['Algo', 'BackTrack', 5, ['b', 'd', 'g']], ]  

# Create the pandas DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Category', 'Name', 'Marks', 'Alpha'])  

print(df ) 

# how do I select rows from the dataframe that match multiple values?
# doing this with a single value is be easy
desired_name = ['DP', 'Greedy']
small_set = df[df['Name'].isin(desired_name)]
print(small_set)

# what I really want to do is something like
desired_alpha = ['c', 'i']
small_set = df[df['Alpha'].isin(desired_alpha)]
print(small_set)

# The only thing I've been able to figure out is below, but it's ugly
# and painful so guessing there is a better way

set_mask = df['Alpha'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y in x, desired_alpha))  )
set_mask = set_mask.to_frame()

# convert the non-empty arrays to True and other to False

set_mask = set_mask.mask(set_mask['Alpha'].str.len() != 0, True)
set_mask = set_mask.mask(set_mask['Alpha'].str.len() == 0, False)

# Then use the set_mask as a mask like df[set_mask] but that doesn't work since
# the values in set_mask are not boolean -- which is a different problem
```

Comment: `small_set = df[df['Name'].isin(desired_alpha)]`? do you mean `df["Alpha"]`?

Comment: can you give an example output?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant good catch, that was/is the code that I wanted working that @Grismar posted below.  I've fixed the example above for those that read later.

Answer (score 1):

Less 'painful' in my opinion:

```
# This replaces "what I really want to do is something like" section, entire solution
desired_alpha = ['c', 'i']
small_set = df[df['Alpha'].apply(lambda x: any([y in x for y in desired_alpha]))]
print(small_set)
```

Explanation:

`any([y in x for y in desired_alpha])` takes a value from the `'Alpha'` column (`x`) and checks if any of the values in `desired_alpha` show up in `x`.

By applying that as a function to the `'Alpha'` column of df: `df['Alpha'].apply(lambda x: any([y in x for y in desired_alpha]))`, you get a series of `bool` values - that can then be used to select the solution you are after.

Written out as code long form:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['DS', 'Linked_list', 10, ['a', 'b', 'c']], 
        ['DS', 'Stack', 9, ['d', 'e', 'c']], 
        ['DS', 'Queue', 7, ['f', 'g', 'i']], 
        ['Algo', 'Greedy', 8, ['r', 's', 'c']], 
        ['Algo', 'DP', 6, ['t', 'r', 'g']], 
        ['Algo', 'BackTrack', 5, ['b', 'd', 'g']], ]  

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Category', 'Name', 'Marks', 'Alpha'])  

desired = ['c', 'i']


def contains_desired(x):
    global desired
    return any([y in x for y in desired])


selection = df['Alpha'].apply(contains_desired)
small_set = df[selection]
print(small_set)
```

Output:

```
  Category         Name  Marks      Alpha
0       DS  Linked_list     10  [a, b, c]
1       DS        Stack      9  [d, e, c]
2       DS        Queue      7  [f, g, i]
3     Algo       Greedy      8  [r, s, c]
```

Note: change `any()` to `all()` if you want to match only options that have both `i` and `c`, but I assumed that was not the case because of your example data.

Comment: well done, that worked like a charm!  Thanks for the detailed explanation as well, that helped my understanding ... I've learned something which is a great way to start the day.

Comment: Some users have added answers indicating they think this is the appropriate answer. If you agree, consider clicking the checkmark, so that your question no longer appears as unanswered and others can find it more easily when they have a similar problem.